# How to use <component :is=""> in vue 3 script setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am using the experimental [script setup](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/script-setup-2/active-rfcs/0000-script-setup.md) to create a learn enviroment. I got a selfmade navigation bar with open a single component.

I am having trouble using the `<component :is="" />` method. This method is described in the docs under [component basics -> dynamic-components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dynamic-components)

In the Vue 3 Composition API, it works as expected:

```html
<template>
  <NavigationBar
    @switchTab="changeTab"
    :activeTab="tab"
  />
  <component :is="tab" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar.vue'
import TemplateSyntax from './components/TemplateSyntax.vue'
import DataPropsAndMethods from './components/DataPropsAndMethods.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    NavigationBar,
    TemplateSyntax,
    DataPropsAndMethods
  },
  setup () {
    const tab = ref('DataPropsAndMethods')
    function changeTab (newTab) {
      tab.value = newTab
    }

    return {
      changeTab,
      tab
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

**My approach with the `script setup` fails:**

```html
<template>
  <NavigationBar
    @switchTab="changeTab"
    :activeTab="tab"
  />
  <component :is="tab" />
</template>

<script setup>
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar.vue'
import TemplateSyntax from './components/TemplateSyntax.vue'
import DataPropsAndMethods from './components/DataPropsAndMethods.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const tab = ref('DataPropsAndMethods')
function changeTab (newTab) {
  tab.value = newTab
}
</script>
```

do you got any idea how to solve this with the script setup method?

Comment: import {defineAsyncComponent} from "vue"
<component :is="defineAsyncComponent(()=>import(`../components/${yourComponent}`))"></component>

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems with `<script setup>`, `tab` needs to reference the component definition itself instead of the component name.

To reference the component definition, which does not need reactivity, use [`markRaw()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#markraw) before setting `tab.value`:

```html
<script setup>
import DataPropsAndMethods from './components/DataPropsAndMethods.vue'
import { ref, markRaw } from 'vue'

const tab = ref(null)

changeTab(DataPropsAndMethods)

// newTab: component definition (not a string)
function changeTab (newTab) {
  tab.value = markRaw(newTab)
}
</script>
```

[demo 1](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

If you need to pass the component name to `changeTab()`, you could use a lookup:

```html
<script setup>
import DataPropsAndMethods from './components/DataPropsAndMethods.vue'
import { ref, markRaw } from 'vue'

const tab = ref(null)

changeTab('DataPropsAndMethods')

// newTab: component name (string)
function changeTab (newTab) {
  const lookup = {
    DataPropsAndMethods,
    /* ...other component definitions */
  }
  tab.value = markRaw(lookup[newTab])
}
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

*Tested with Vue `3.0.9` setup with Vue CLI `5.0.0-alpha.8`*