# Vue <script setup> - how to deal with multiple dynamic components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

It seems that it is impossible to convert the Options API code below to `<script setup>`:

```js
    <template>
      <div>
        <component :is="layout">
          <router-view/>
        </component>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    const defaultLayout = 'default'
    
    import Dark from './layouts/dark.vue'
    import Light from './layouts/light.vue'
    import Default from './layouts/default.vue'
    
    export default {
      name: 'App',
    
      components: {
        Dark,
        Light,
        Default
      },
    
      computed: {
        layout () {
          return (this.$route.meta.layout || defaultLayout)
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

My attempt:

```js
    <script setup>
    import { computed } from 'vue'
    import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
    
    import Dark from './layouts/dark.vue'
    import Light from './layouts/light.vue'
    import Default from './layouts/default.vue'
    
    const router = useRouter()
    const route = useRoute()
    
    const defaultLayout = 'default'
    const layout = computed(() => route.meta.layout || defaultLayout )
    </script>
```

**Result:**

No layout is loaded with the `<script setup>` option but just a `<default>`, `<dark>`, or `<light>` block, for example:

```html
    <div id="app">
    <default>
    ...
    ...
    </default>
    </div>
```

According to the doc [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#using-components), we can use a ternary:

```html
    <component :is="someCondition ? Foo : Bar" />
```

But that is not ideal. As you might have more than 2 dynamic components to work out. We can't make the ternary too long. Can we?

Any ideas?

Comment: I got a similar question about to use `component :is=""` with `script setup`. [Hope it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384268/how-to-use-component-is-in-vue-3-script-setup)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is to return the referenced variable rather than it's name.

```js
    <script setup>
    import { computed } from 'vue'
    import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'
    
    import Dark from './layouts/dark.vue'
    import Light from './layouts/light.vue'
    import Default from './layouts/default.vue'
    
    const router = useRouter()
    const route = useRoute()
    
    const layouts = {
      default: Default,
      light: Light,
      dark: Dark
    };
    
    const defaultLayout = 'default'
    const layout = computed(() => layouts[route.meta.layout || defaultLayout] )
    </script>
```

**Reason**

While with options API components are [registered locally](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-registration.html#local-registration) and can be resolved by it's name (string key), with `<script setup>` the components are used [directly without registration](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0040-script-setup.md#using-components) so it is not possible to use `string` key to resolve them...

Comment: As per the vue's documentation, you can use the name string of a component and vue will resolve that component as long as it is registered in that component. And as per vue's documentation a component is registered when importing that component when using script setup. No mention of not being able to use the string name in script setup.