# Using <component> :is in Vue <script setup>

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I want a button to toggle between two views on click. The code is:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="switchSheet">{{ currentSheet }}</button>
  <component :is="sheetView" :key="componentKey" />
</template>

<script setup>
import DisplaySheetClassrooms from "./components/ds-classrooms.vue";
import DisplaySheetChromebooks from "./components/ds-chromebooks.vue";

let sheetView = DisplaySheetClassrooms;
let currentSheet = ref("HS Classrooms");

const switchSheet = () => {
  if (sheetView == DisplaySheetClassrooms) {
    sheetView = DisplaySheetChromebooks;
    currentSheet.value = "HS Chromebooks";
  } else {
    sheetView = DisplaySheetClassrooms;
    currentSheet.value = "HS Classrooms";
  }
};
```

Documentation states

> ":is can contain either:
>
> ```
> the name string of a registered component, OR
> the actual imported component object"
> ```

I am using the actual imported component but looking at Devtools switchView never changes value on click. I also tried it with string quotes and still no good. I tried solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384268/how-to-use-component-is-in-vue-3-script-setup) but it did not work for me. Could somebody clarify how to get this working . Thanks in advance.

Comment: const sheetView = ref('DisplaySheetClassrooms');
const currentSheet  = ref('HS Classrooms');

function switchSheet() {
    sheetView.value === 'DisplaySheetClassrooms' ? sheetView.value = 'DisplaySheetChromebooks' : sheetView.value = 'DisplaySheetClassrooms';
     sheetView.value === 'DisplaySheetClassrooms' ? currentSheet.value = 'HS Classrooms' : currentSheet.value = 'HS Chromebooks';
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

Use a components object and have the component name key (`sheetView` in your case) used to target the key in the `component :is` value

example:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="switchSheet">{{ currentSheet }}</button>
  <component :is="components[currentSheet]" :key="currentSheet" />
</template>

<script setup>
import DisplaySheetClassrooms from "./components/ds-classrooms.vue";
import DisplaySheetChromebooks from "./components/ds-chromebooks.vue";

let currentSheet = ref("DisplaySheetChromebooks");

// create an object key (doesn't need to be a ref)
const components = {
  DisplaySheetChromebooks,
  DisplaySheetClassrooms,
}

const switchSheet = () => {
  if (currentSheet === "DisplaySheetClassrooms) {
    currentSheet = "DisplaySheetChromebooks";
  } else {
    currentSheet = "DisplaySheetClassrooms";
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just had to add .value to all currentSheet occurences. Gotta tell you I'm getting a little sick of composition API. Things that took 15mins take an hour now. Steeper learning curve then I first thought. There's always a little gotcha. Are you finding it the same?

Comment: I'm not keen on the `<script setup>`, but I do like the composition API. That said, I do most of the stuff in svelte these days anyway. I get the impression that `<script setup>` is there to match the svelte experience, but it does seem a little incomplete. There certain things that just don't work there, such as typing props with typescript if I remember correctly.

Comment: I just feel where always chasing the next big thing when you go down framework rabbit hole. I'm going to be making a concerted effort to do as much as possible with plain vanilla JS in future.