# Vue 3: component `:is` in for loop fails

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to loop over a list of component described by **strings** (I get the name of the component from another , like `const componentTreeName = ["CompA", "CompA"]`.

My code is a simple as:

```js
<script setup>
    import CompA from './CompA.vue'
    import { ref } from 'vue'

    // I do NOT want to use [CompA, CompA] because my inputs are strings
    const componentTreeName = ["CompA", "CompA"]
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Demo</h1>
  <template v-for="compName in componentTreeName">
    <component :is="compName"></component>
  </template>
</template>
```

[Demo here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cblx0aW1wb3J0IENvbXBBIGZyb20gJy4vQ29tcEEudnVlJ1xuXHRpbXBvcnQgeyByZWYgfSBmcm9tICd2dWUnXG5cbiAgLy8gSSBkbyBOT1Qgd2FudCB0byB1c2UgW0NvbXBBLCBDb21wQV0gYmVjYXVzZSBteSBpbnB1dHMgYXJlIHN0cmluZ3Ncblx0Y29uc3QgY29tcG9uZW50VHJlZU5hbWUgPSBbXCJDb21wQVwiLCBcIkNvbXBBXCJdXG48L3NjcmlwdD5cblxuPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8aDE+RGVtbzwvaDE+XG4gIDx0ZW1wbGF0ZSB2LWZvcj1cImNvbXBOYW1lIGluIGNvbXBvbmVudFRyZWVOYW1lXCI+XG4gICAgPGNvbXBvbmVudCA6aXM9XCJjb21wTmFtZVwiPjwvY29tcG9uZW50PlxuICA8L3RlbXBsYXRlPlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJ2dWVcIjogXCJodHRwczovL3NmYy52dWVqcy5vcmcvdnVlLnJ1bnRpbWUuZXNtLWJyb3dzZXIuanNcIlxuICB9XG59IiwiQ29tcEEudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCB7IHJlZiB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZSdcblxuY29uc3QgbXNnID0gcmVmKCdQdXQgdGl0bGUgc2xpZGUgaGVyZScpXG48L3NjcmlwdD5cblxuPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8aDI+e3sgbXNnIH19PC9oMj5cbiAgPGlucHV0IHYtbW9kZWw9XCJtc2dcIj5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+IiwiVGFibGUudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCB7IHJlZiB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZSdcbmluamVjdChcIm1haW5EYXRhXCIpXG5jb25zdCBtc2cgPSByZWYoJ0hlbGxvIFdvcmxkIScpXG48L3NjcmlwdD5cblxuPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8aDI+XG4gICAgVGFibGUgZGVzIG1hdGnDqHJlc1xuICA8L2gyPlxuICBcbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+In0=)

**EDIT**

I tried [this](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) with not much success.

Comment: got a similar problem, hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384268/how-to-use-component-is-in-vue-3-script-setup - in the answer is a working demo with a stringification

Comment: Thanks. The problem of the proposed solution is that the lookup function would not deal with globally registered components. I also tried to use resolveComponent, but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 5):

When using `script setup`, you need to reference the component and not the name or key.

To get it to work, I would use an object where the string can be used as a key to target the component from an object like this:

```html
<script setup>
    import CompA from './CompA.vue'
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    const components = {CompA};

    // I do NOT want to use [CompA, CompA] because my inputs are strings
    const componentTreeName = ["CompA", "CompA"]
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Demo</h1>
  <template v-for="compName in componentTreeName">
    <component :is="components[compName]"></component>
  </template>
</template>
```

To use a global component, you could assign components by pulling them from the app context. But this would require the `app` context to be available and the keys known.

example:

```js
import { app } from '../MyApp.js'
const components = {
  CompA: app.component('CompA')
}
```

I haven't tested this, but this might be worth a try to check with `getCurrentInstance`

```js
import { ref,getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
const components = getCurrentInstance().appContext.components;
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this solution does not work for components registered globally. And why is setup so special?

Comment: `<script setup>` is syntactical sugar that does a bunch of "magic" and in order to support that , some things just behave differently.

Comment: Ok. But does that mean that I can't support global components? I really don't want to assume that the parent component is aware of all components that can be defined in the child component.

Comment: updated answer, I haven't tested using the `getCurrentInstance`, but that might be worth a try too.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So I tried to `getCurrentInstance` thing, but unfortunately I can't make it work (and it turns out the documentation has changed recently, and I can't find anymore any documentation on it, and the search functionality of the vuejs website does not help).

Comment: the problem in the `sfc.vuejs` examples is that the components are not getting registered as global components. In the example code and in the demos, you are using `import CompA from './CompA.vue'` which doesn't make it globally accessible, and leaves the `getCurrentInstance().appContext.components` object empty

Comment: Ah I see... Actually, I tried with Vite.js, and it seems that the best solution to handle both local and global thing is to just use a second `<script>` to import local components, and global components will automatically be used with the above syntax https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5411

Comment: You can maybe also add this to your answer (maybe as an alternative, otherwise your method requires to check both the `getCurrentInstance().appContext.components` and the manual array), and I'll be happy to accept it!

Comment: Does the non-setup script make it work with globally registered components?

Comment: In my tests yes.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`resolveComponent()`](https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#resolvecomponent) on the component name to look up the global component by name:

```html
<script setup>
import { resolveComponent, markRaw } from 'vue'
const myGlobalComp = markRaw(resolveComponent('my-global-component'))
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="myGlobalComp" />
<template>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-dynamic-components-in-script-setup?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FGlobals.vue)

If you have a mix of locally and globally registered components, you can use a lookup for local components, and fall back to `resolveComponent()` for globals:

```html
<script setup>
import LocalComponentA from '@/components/LocalComponentA.vue'
import LocalComponentB from '@/components/LocalComponentB.vue'
import { resolveComponent, markRaw } from 'vue'

const localComponents = {
  LocalComponentA,
  LocalComponentB,
}

const lookupComponent = name => {
  const c = localComponents[name] ?? resolveComponent(name)
  return markRaw(c)
}

const componentList = [
  'GlobalComponentA',
  'GlobalComponentB',
  'LocalComponentA',
  'LocalComponentB',
].map(lookupComponent)
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="c" v-for="c in componentList" />
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-dynamic-components-in-script-setup?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FLocalsAndGlobals.vue)

***Note:** [`markRaw`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#markraw) is used on the component definition because no reactivity is needed on it.*