# Composition API + script setup Dynamic component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I want to implement simple tabs using script setup and composition API

```
<script setup>
import Timeline from './Timeline.vue';
import Profile from './Profile.vue';
import Groups from './Groups.vue';

const currentTab = ref('Timeline')
const tabs = ref(['Timeline', 'Profile', 'Groups'])
</script>

<template>
    <div class="tabs">
       <div v-for="tab in tabs"
       :key="tab"
       @click="currentTab = tab" v-text="tab"

       <component :is="currentTab"></component>
    </div>
</template>
```

But this code will only result `<timeline></timeline>` instead of the actual content of the Timeline component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384268/how-to-use-component-is-in-vue-3-script-setup) when using the `<script setup>`-method you need to pass the actual object of the component to the `:is` instead of the string.

[See this Example here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

Here is also the code itself:

```html
<script setup>
import Timeline from './Timeline.vue';
import Profile from './Profile.vue';
import Groups from './Groups.vue';
import { shallowRef } from 'vue';

const currentTab = shallowRef(Timeline);
const tabs = [Timeline, Profile, Groups];
</script>

<template>
    <div class="tabs">
       <div v-for="tab in tabs"
        :key="tab"
        @click="currentTab = tab" v-text="tab.__name">
      </div>

    </div>
  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="currentTab"></component>
  </keep-alive>
</template>
```